# Can someone tell me how to pass this array into my main method so it prints?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to pass my array and it does not print out the sumAllColumnsRows and I have searched alot of sites and I am not sure how to print what the code is doing. being passed from the method below.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter dimension of an nxn matrix ");
    int x=input.nextInt();
    double[][] nxn=new double[x][x];
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter row " + (i) + ": ");
        for(int j=0;j<x;j++){
            nxn[i][j]=input.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sumAllColumnsRows(m, column, rowColumn));
}

public static double sumAllColumnsRows(double[][] m, boolean column, int rowColumn)
{
    double total=0;
    for (int col = 0; col < m[0].length; col++) {
        int colSum = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
            colSum += m[row][col];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of the elements at col " + col + " is: " + colSum);
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
        int rowSum = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < m[row].length; col++) {
            rowSum += m[row][col];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of the elements at row " + row + " is: " + rowSum);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: First, it does not return an array, but rather a `double`. Also, add a call to `input.readLine` at the end of your main method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your problem is probably identified here, but I think you might have other problems. First:

```
double[][] nxn=new double[x][x];
...
System.out.println(sumAllColumnsRows(m, column, rowColumn));
```

You are defining your variable non but passing m. You also have no variables column and rowColumn. I imagine this code doesn't compile.

Note, however, that your sumAllColumnsRows doesn't actually use those second two arguments.

The error messages from javac should have helped figure this out.

Comment: Thank you, I gave you both an upvote. Now I changed my code to this... and I am just not sure what to put in the line for System.prnt.ln
public static void main(String[] args){
  
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter dimension of an nxn matrix ");
    int x=input.nextInt();
    double[][] nxn=new double[x][x];
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter row " + (i) + ": ");
    for(int j=0;j<x;j++){
    nxn[i][j]=input.nextDouble();
    }
    }
    System.out.println(sumAllColumnsRows(nxn, x, i));
}

Comment: If you don't have your problems figured out, perhaps update your question with more readable code and let us know -- does it compile? Run? What happens? What specifically still has you confused.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding to the total variable in the sumAllColumnsRows.  It will always return 0.

```
public static double sumAllColumnsRows(double[][] m, boolean column, int rowColumn) {
    double total = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < m[0].length; col++) {
        int colSum = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
            colSum += m[row][col];
        }
        total += colSum;
        System.out.println("Sum of the elements at col " + col + " is: " + colSum);
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
        int rowSum = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < m[row].length; col++) {
            rowSum += m[row][col];
        }
        total += rowSum;
        System.out.println("Sum of the elements at row " + row + " is: " + rowSum);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I gave you both an upvote. Now I changed my code to this... and I am just not sure what to put in the line for System.prnt.ln public static void main(String[] args){ Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in); System.out.print("Enter dimension of an nxn matrix "); int x=input.nextInt(); double[][] nxn=new double[x][x]; for(int i=0;i<x;i++){ System.out.print("Enter row " + (i) + ": "); for(int j=0;j<x;j++){ nxn[i][j]=input.nextDouble(); } } System.out.println(sumAllColumnsRows(nxn, x, i)); }